# How stop the flicker in the SideNav caused by the useEffect which fetches some data on every render - Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a parent component that holds a SideBar component and an  that renders out the nested routed components in the parent. The SideBar has useEffect hook to make an API call to retrieve some data such as the name of the user, and if the user is verified which I use to show the name of the user on the top of the Nav and conditionally render buttons. Now because of the nested routing the SideBar re-renders every time. Hence the useEffect hook makes the API call every time which makes the layout flicker because it takes a small time to get the data from the async function. Is there any way to stop that flicker? below is the code

**SideBar.js**

```
const SideBar = (props) => {
  // selecting slices for getting user data
  const { authTokens, user } = useSelector((state) => state.login);

  // setting states
  const [teacher, setTeacher] = useState(null); //to store the teacher detail
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const constant = localStorage.getItem("token") ? true : null;

  useEffect(() => {
    // setting the loading true to wait for the data
    setLoading(true);

    /*
    this is the procedure to retrive data from an async api call because we
    cannot directly use async calls so we have to wrap them inside another small function.
    */

    const fectData = async () => {
      //await here is neccessary to wait for the promise to get resolved
      let response = await fetchTeacherDetail(user.user_id);
      setTeacher(response.data);
      setLoading(false);
    };

    fectData();
  }, [constant]);

  const profileButton = (
    <Fragment>
      <NavLink activeclassname="acitve" to="/teacher/profile">
        <i class="fas fa-user"></i>Profile
      </NavLink>
    </Fragment>
  );

  const enterDetails = (
    <Fragment>
      <NavLink activeclassname="acitve" to="/teacher/submit-info">
        <i class="fas fa-pen"></i> Enter Details
      </NavLink>
    </Fragment>
  );

  return (
    <SideNav>
      <UserNameContainer>
        <p>{!loading && teacher.name}</p>
      </UserNameContainer>
      <ButtonContainer>
        <Fragment>
          {!loading && teacher.is_verified ? profileButton : enterDetails}
        </Fragment>
        <NavLink activeclassname="acitve" to="info">
          <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i> My Information
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink activeclassname="acitve" to="student-requests">
          <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i> Requests
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink activeclassname="acitve" to="enrolled-student">
          <i class="fas fa-user-graduate"></i> My Students
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink activeclassname="acitve" to="payment">
          <i class="fas fa-rupee-sign"></i> Payments
        </NavLink>
      </ButtonContainer>
    </SideNav>
  );
};

export default SideBar;
```

**Dashboard.js**

```
return (
    <Container>
      <SideBar />

      <ContentMainContainer>
        {/* this makes the nested routes display here */}
        <Outlet />
      </ContentMainContainer>
    </Container>
  );
```

[image: added the flicker gif]

The gif is showing only one flicker perhaps because the chrome capture but it happens for all the links I click.

Please suggest me to avoid this flicker.

Comment: have you tried useLayoutEffect over useEffect ?

Comment: @BARNOWL No, I am a beginner actually, can you show me the implementation by writing an ans? please

Comment: can you try it to use useLayoutEffect, its imported from react the same way useEffect is

Comment: @BARNOWL the flickering still exists

Comment: If you could reproduce this issue on codesandbox that would be helpful

Comment: @BARNOWL I think it may not be possible because it involves an API request that is being made to the backend in localhost,  
 I have put the gif for the same purpose. Please can you check the codes and the gif?

Comment: If you are using React 18, I believe you can use the new useDeferredValue hook to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The component is flickering because the height of the `<p>` tag containing the name is changing. You can try setting a height for it. The easiest way to do that is by setting the style inline, like this:

```
<p style={{minHeight: '1rem'}}>{!loading && teacher.name}</p>
```

Just remember, every time you remove or add some piece of content, it will possibly affect everything else.

Comment: Still the flicker persists. It looks like on every click  the side bar re-renders, the name disappears and appears again after the API is called