# Unusual Render and Re-renders of the child and parent component causing layout flicker

Tags: reactjs, rendering, react-component

I am trying to make a dashboard for teachers where the details of the teachers would be displayed. I am using nested routing to display the components related to the teacher's dashboard and therefore I have sidebar too. I was facing a flicker in the layout of the side bar while navigating from one route to another about which i have mentioned in my another question [How stop the flicker in the SideNav caused by the useEffect which fetches some data on every render - Reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71904281/16425029?stw=2). So I was playing with code and did some console logs to track exactly what is happening to the component and found out that there is a **unusual** rendering of the components. I am making an api call inside the useEffect of the parent and do not know if thats causing an issue. Below is all the codes of the parent and child

**Dashboard (Parent Component)**

```
const TeacherDashboard = () => {
  // selecting slices for getting user data
  const { authTokens, user } = useSelector((state) => state.login);

  // setting states
  const [teacher, setTeacher] = useState(null); //to store the teacher detail
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    // setting the loading tru to wait for the data
    setLoading(true);

    /*
    this is the procedure to retrive data from an async api call because we
    cannot directly use async calls so we have to wrap them inside another small function.
    */

    const fectData = async () => {
      //await here is neccessary to wait for the promise to get resolved
      let response = await fetchTeacherDetail(user.user_id);
      setTeacher(response.data);
      setLoading(false);
    };

    fectData();
  }, []);

  console.log("Rendered Dashboard");

  return (
    <Container>
      <SideBar name={!loading && teacher.name} />

      <ContentMainContainer>
        {/* this makes the nested routes display here */}
        <Outlet />
      </ContentMainContainer>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

**SideBar (Child Component)**

```
const SideBar = (props) => {
  // selecting slices for getting user data
  const { authTokens, user } = useSelector((state) => state.login);

  // setting states
  const [teacher, setTeacher] = useState(null); //to store the teacher detail
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  console.log("The SideBar has rendered");

  const profileButton = (
    <Fragment>
      <NavLink activeclassname="acitve" to="/teacher/profile">
        <i className="fas fa-user"></i>Profile
      </NavLink>
    </Fragment>
  );

  const enterDetails = (
    <Fragment>
      <NavLink activeclassname="acitve" to="/teacher/profile">
        <i className="fas fa-pen"></i> Enter Details
      </NavLink>
    </Fragment>
  );

  return (
    <SideNav>
      <UserNameContainer>
        <p>{props.name}</p>
      </UserNameContainer>
      <ButtonContainer>
        {/* <Fragment>
          {!loading && teacher.is_verified ? profileButton : enterDetails}
        </Fragment> */}
        <NavLink activeclassname="acitve" to="info">
          <i className="fas fa-info-circle"></i> My Information
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink activeclassname="acitve" to="student-requests">
          <i className="fas fa-user-plus"></i> Requests
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink activeclassname="acitve" to="enrolled-student">
          <i className="fas fa-user-graduate"></i> My Students
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink activeclassname="acitve" to="payment">
          <i className="fas fa-rupee-sign"></i> Payments
        </NavLink>
      </ButtonContainer>
    </SideNav>
  );
};

export default memo(SideBar);
```

And now the Console Logs about how the components are rendering

**on first load after login in**

```
Rendered Dashboard 
SideBar.js:16 The SideBar has rendered
TeacherDashboard.js:35 use effect called
TeacherDashboard.js:38 Rendered Dashboard 
TeacherDashboard.js:38 Rendered Dashboard 
SideBar.js:16 The SideBar has rendered
```

**next on clicking on any link to route to one of the nested route**

```
Rendered Dashboard 
SideBar.js:16 The SideBar has rendered
TeacherDashboard.js:35 use effect called
TeacherDashboard.js:38 Rendered Dashboard 
TeacherDashboard.js:38 Rendered Dashboard 
SideBar.js:16 The SideBar has rendered
```

**on the third click**

```
Rendered Dashboard 
SideBar.js:16 The SideBar has rendered
TeacherDashboard.js:38 Rendered Dashboard 
SideBar.js:16 The SideBar has rendered
TeacherDashboard.js:35 use effect called
TeacherDashboard.js:38 Rendered Dashboard 
TeacherDashboard.js:38 Rendered Dashboard 
SideBar.js:16 The SideBar has rendered
```

the components are getting rendered in this pattern. Please help me to rectify this problem of unusual re-rendering and eventually stop the flicker. I am new to react do not understand how to solve it

**The Flickering Problem on the side bar**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Every time you trigger the useEffect in the parent, you set the `loading` state to true. This will cause the `name` prop you send to the SideBar to toggle between a string and false/undefined, which will trigger a re-render in the Sidebar

Comment: So please suggest to me what should I do. I want to display the name of the user on the top of the sidebar like Twitter does, for this, I have to make an API call. I tried doing it only on the sidebar component but the problem still persists with the same pattern.

Comment: Can you describe the flickering? Could it be just because the name disappears and reappears?

Comment: Yes, I have attached a question where I asked specifically about the flickering. I have attached there a gif to show what is happening

Comment: I'll have a look at that one too

Comment: I have edited this question with the gif

Comment: This definitely happens because the name keeps appearing/disappearing. Is the name disappearing when you fetch a new teacher important? I think I would have let the "old" name stay there until the new name is ready - that is, only update the name when you have a success or error from you fetch request. In general, that will cause a lot less flickers

Comment: I am not fecthing a new teacher this dasboard is specific to that particular teacher after he log in. So the name should stay in the teacher stay. but on clicking the side bar loads too hence calls the API again. Will you please put an ans as to what you have done that you have commented